# CentOS Linux screen -ls does not list sessions

Tags: linux, display

screen -ls does not list sessions anymore. It did work before, I can not remember what mistakes I have made. However I still can ls /var/run/screen/S-qlu to see all the sessions.

Is there anybody who know the reason? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share the output you **do** get?

Comment: When I typed the command screen -ls, there is no output. It just looks like running forever. I have to use ctrl+c to terminate it.  Could it be the reason that screen can not find path or I logged out somehow?

Comment: I am in the exact same situation, did you found a solution ?